# Search google for my website

Tags: web, seo

I have a weird problem with Google when I search for my web address. The problem is when I type in Google search ex. mydomain.com, the results are from alldomain.com - not from my website, and Google give a link "Search instead for mydomain.com", and I need to click that link to give results for mydomain.com. What can I do to fix this problem?

Here is what I mean:[image]

Comment: Are you looking for results IN your domain, or are you just looking to have your website show up when you search for it.

Comment: @GiovanniB look at the image added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's a new website and you don't have a [google-webmaster](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) account - you should open one. It's important to register your website (to let Google know you have a new website) so that it'll start index it ASAP.
If it's an "old" website that suddenly stopped appearing on google search results - you can read the answer I posted [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/31893/13618).

Comment: it's a new site, and I was wondering is this normal in google

Comment: it could take up to a few days before google's servers index your website. I also recommend reading about the [*sandbox effect*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_effect)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for results from one website you should search for:

```
SEARCH STRING site:mydomain.com
```

Comment: look at the image added in my post